# changing default controller in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I tried to set homepage as another controller than indexController by adding this line in application.ini

```
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName="site"
```

I don't see any changes, index controller load again, how do i change this pls help.

Comment: This is supposed to work. Could you copy paste your application.ini and your bootstrap?

Comment: One more thing, is "site" a valid controller?

Comment: that's all my bootstrap     protected function _initNavigation()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();
        $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($this->getOption('navigation'));
        $view->navigation($navigation);
    }

Comment: did you add `resources.frontController.defaultControllerName="site"` in the good section of your application.ini (production, dev...) ?

Comment: i did add it on [development : production] and also production and i also tried default.resources.frontController.defaultControllerName="site" no luck, just nothing happen i get index controller loaded as usual

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8211/discussion-between-liyali-and-rajendra)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you do not have modular structure then setting folowing to application.ini should work

```
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "site"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "action"
```

If you have modular structure then add following

```
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "site"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "actionName"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "moduleName"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

I always add such settings under [production] of my application.ini because these settings are same for other staging, dev, testing environments, i inherit production settings like this

```
[staging: production]
[development : staging]
```

Make sure you create the controller and action as you mention in application.ini in right form. Also make sure that you are not doing any forwards which is surpassing the settings of application.ini

hope this helps